# Changing the tableview's content inset

Tags: ios, swift

I am changing content insets in swift. But I want to change just bottom inset. But my code changing each inset.

```
let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
self.tableView.contentInset = edgeInsets
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsets
```

I want to change only bottom inset and other insets should be the default insets. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter in the `UIEdgeInsetsMake` function is the parameter that sets the bottom inset.

In your case you want `let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottomValue, 0)`.

However, because you are using Swift, it's more "swifty" to use `UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: valueYouWant, right: 0)`

Comment: Before the giving top inset to 0 :http://prntscr.com/7j0078   After: http://prntscr.com/7j00ec I think there is should be the default value expect 0

Comment: That's because the `UIViewController` has property `automaticallyAdjustsContentInsets` set to `YES` so it would automatically set the top content inset to 64. Once you manually set the insets it changes this.